# Creating an environment in Latex

Tags: latex

Hi I'm trying to create an environment in Latex that recreates the effect of the following.

```
\colorbox{bg}{\ttfamily{\color[RGB]{222,222,222}
Hello
Whats up
}
}
```

I want to be able to say.

```
\begin{bashcommands}
Hello
Whats Up
\end{bashcommands}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\makeatletter\newenvironment{bc_box}{%
   \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}}{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
   \colorbox{bg}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}
}\makeatother

\newenvironment{bashcommands}{
    \begin{bc_box}\ttfamily\color[RGB]{222,222,222}
}{                                    
    \end{bc_box}
}
```

[See this, as well.](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=282787)

Comment: Seems like a really winded way of doing it.
I saw the same answer on answers.google.com.

I was hoping there was a way to simply insert the command into the box. But if that doesn't work, I guess I'll have to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this http://kuscsik.blogspot.com/2006/12/how-to-create-new-environment-in-latex.html

Comment: While that is the obvious method, it doesn't really work in the case I'm trying to use it for. I guess it might have something to do with the colorbox command.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Donald Arseneau's framed.sty](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/framed/), you can do this, which would also work nicely if you need to span multiple pages.

```
\newenvironment{bashcommands}{%
  \definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{bg}%
  \begin{shaded}\ttfamily\color[RGB]{222,222,222}%
}{%
  \end{shaded}%
}
```